# How to Generate Tones with Accurate Timing in Windows 10

Tags: python, audio

How can tones with accurate timing be generated on a Windows 10 PC?  Specifically, I want the PC to play a tone when one of the handshake inputs on an RS232 COM port is active.  This is for a remote amateur radio application, to provide a local monitor for sending Morse Code (CW in ham radio jargon).  Putting aside the input signal for now, I tried the Python code below to generate tones with fixed timing.  The timing is not accurate or repeatable enough for the intended purpose; I probably need about 3 ms accuracy.

I understand that Windows is not a real-time operating system, and yet there are music applications that seem to generate perfectly timed music.

```
# Morse code CQ - Not very good timing on Windows 10 PC
import time
import winsound

# "C"
winsound.Beep(440, 300)
time.sleep(0.1)
winsound.Beep(440, 100)
time.sleep(0.1)
winsound.Beep(440, 300)
time.sleep(0.1)
winsound.Beep(440, 100)

time.sleep(0.7)

# "Q"
winsound.Beep(440, 300)
time.sleep(0.1)
winsound.Beep(440, 300)
time.sleep(0.1)
winsound.Beep(440, 100)
time.sleep(0.1)
winsound.Beep(440, 300)
```

Note:  This is my first question on stack overflow.  Any feedback on how to best post questions is appreciated.

Comment: Hi Eliot.  If you use an audio API rather than the old PC speaker emulation, you'll get full control over the audio data and can set sample-accurate timing.  I'm not a Python person, but in looking at `winsound`, it looks like you can use `winsound.PlaySound()` to play arbitrary PCM audio data.  Perhaps you can generate a PCM buffer for playback.

Comment: @Brad - Thank you for the suggestion.  I will look into winsound.PlaySound(), and will update this comment or my original post with the outcome.